# PHP (MYSQL) Client Api Version Update

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, cpanel, whm

I use WHM / CPANEL

I have updated MYSQL / MariaDB

[image: IMG - 1 - MYSQL/MARIADB]

Currently show MariaDB 10.2 installed

PHPMYADMIN : Server version: 10.2.17-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

[image: IMG - 2 PHPMYADMIN]

But php client api version mysqlnd looks as 5.0.11-dev

[image: IMG - 3 - PHPINFO 5.x]

I want to have php client api version 10.2

[image: IMG - 4 PHPINFO 10.X]

easy apache php mysql client version not updated

Comment: A client API version of 5.0.11 is perfectly workable with MariaDB-10.2.7. No major change has occurred in the client connection to the server. There are no major features you'll be missing out of. Any attempt to fix this will give you more WHM / CPanel troubles than you already have.

Comment: I understand but, Our software is not compatible with client api version 5.0.11. MariaDB - unfortunately it needs to be 10.2.7

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your two 'MySQL Support' images. Can you show an error related to your software incompatibility with the client api?

Comment: Just tell us that update the mysql version to 10.2 otherwise the software will not work. (I'm badly sorry in English)

Comment: Is there no way to update this?